# How can I change the amount RAM in a virtual machine without powering off

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have a VM in my computer in a saved state.
The RAM assigned is 8GB.  When I start it then it gives error as HOST RAM is less than RAM on VM.

However, to reduce the RAM I need to power off the VM. But if I power off, then it loses the saved state, which I don't want.

What else I can do?

I have Windows 7 host and Ubuntu VM and using Virtual Box 5.

Comment: It is real simply.  You can't change the amount of RAM that would be allocated to the virtual machine while it is running.  How do you even have a virtual machine in a saved state in this configuration?

Comment: @Ramhound  I have vm in 4 snapshots and if restore snapshot then it go to that state

Comment: Don't run more virtual machines assigned to more memory, then your machine, can actually support

Comment: ESXI will allow you to add ram to a machine while its running, if configured in advance, but not remove it, and virtualbox does not support either. moreso only certain win7 skus support hot add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself this: how do you change the RAM of a real computer while it's running?

The answer is simple: this is just not possible, unless the system board supports it specifically. Even so, it has to be under a very specific configuration, and even then, the OS might not recognize it until the system restarts.

You must power off your virtual machine completely, or you can transfer it along with the saved state to a computer (over LAN is the fastest way to do this) with enough RAM to start up the VM and shut down gracefully.

Comment: thanks for that . Is there any difference between RESET VM and Power off VM. Because i find that my application works fine if i reset after starting in Saved state but if i power off then it work work. what can be the reason

Comment: @JohnKaff - There is a difference.  One restarts the virtual machine and the other turns the Virtual Machine off.  Without any specifics about the failure there is no possible way, we can explain your applications behavior, and besides that question seems separate from the question about the virtual machine allocation of memory.